# fullcalendar - duplicate values when replacing text in cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Within fullcalendar.io, I am trying to change the header of the day cell within the monthly view.  Specifically, I would like to add some custom text to the day number of each cell.

However, when I attempt to write text into the cell, it gets duplicated.  My skilz are lacking to determine why.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#TEST').click(function () {
          var elem = $("td").find("[data-date='2014-09-01']");
          elem.text('foo');
      });
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          defaultDate: '2014-09-01',
          events: [{
              backgroundColor: '#66FF33',
              start: '2014-09-01 00:00:00Z',
              allday: true
          }]
      });
  });
```

In a simple example, I am identifying the cell with:

```
elem = $("td").find("[data-date='2014-09-01']");
```

and am attempting to write to the cell with:

```
elem.text('foo');
```

but, I am seeing "foo foo" in the resulting cell. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfyjcc9L/3/)

My attempts to clear the cell (elem.empty()) and use different methods to write the cell (.text,.html) have had no affect.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tables (in `<div class="fc-bg">` and in `<div class="fc-content-skeleton">`, one is rendered over another). Each table has `td` with `data-date='2014-09-01'`. So your code results in setting text "foo" for two `td`.

You can set text only for one of them specifying which one to choose. For example, for `fc-bg` (to save month's day number):

```
var elem = $(".fc-bg td[data-date='2014-09-01']");
elem.text('foo');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfyjcc9L/4/).

Comment: Excellent - thank you.  I completely missed that there were two tables present.

Comment: @BenSchuler you're welcome. That's how all these libraries-plugins work: wrapping wrapped and adding wrapped next to wrapped...